# Delete-repository-hook for git repositories in Bitbucket Server

Tags: git, githooks, bitbucket-server

Does Bitbucket Server provide any routine like a `delete-repository-hook` or maybe it's possible to write an an addon which supplies such a hook?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to write a githook using the Java Plugin Framework which makes easier to add the hook to any of your repositories just enabling or disabling the hook in the Hook tab within the desired repository. I leave you some links I found:

- A nice example: https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bitbucket-protect-unmerged-branch-hook
- A video tutorial (for Stash): https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/01/beer-o-clock-stash-plugin-tutorial/

What I can not find is information about how to catch the action of deleting a branch from Bitbucket UI and not the from the client in order to perform some checkings.

Hope that helps